# How the data being stored on application insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Once particular log is posted, how the data being stored by application insights ?

What is the technology used to index the application insights telemetry?

Comment: there is official documentation on app insights data model https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-data-model/

Answer (score 3):

The underlying storage has evolved several times over the lifetime of the service, and will probably never be *publicly*  documented because that actual model is never actually exposed to anyone.

However, as pointed out in the comments, a form of the data model that's exposed through continuous export is available and documented:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-data-model/

That format is similar to what the various SDK's actually send, enriched with some calculated information that the service calculates for you.

There's also documentation for the Analytics query language and schema:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/

which is *closer* to the final form of how the data is stored, but still is a layer of indirection away so that the service can change the underlying storage without breaking anything publicly exposed to users.